# share session between two different version of playFrameWork

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, session-cookies, stateless-session

Currently two services each running different version of play

they both share same `Secret Key` as well as same `session domain`

**Play Version 2.2.6:**

example of cookie Value:

> b14219d56033ca9aa888a406b31872f5623b892f-myKey=myValue

**Play Version 2.6.7**

example of cookie Value:

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJkYXRhIjp7Imhhc2hlZE1haWwiOiIwN2Q3YzMwODFhYzk0NTljZTcxYmNhMzhhZjdiNjM5MSJ9LCJuYmYiOjE1MTkyMTI1ODMsImlhdCI6MTUxOTIxMjU4M30.eLJr0uQxo3CxSYewHcGbvSZh0IoFybolYa1gdawalyg

So I have a multiple part question:

1. why are the way sessions stored are different? in earlier version I can see each of the key&values whereas the new version is encoded.
2. are session mechanism compatible (i.e. how can I use session values between them?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In play 2.6, play's session support was updated to use JWT. You can fallback to the legacy session mode in the configuration. For more information see the [migration documentation](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26#JWT-Support)

This should enable your applications to access each other data

Comment: thanks alot mate, it works, I'm still learning and got a long way to go.